# Module parse failed: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level

Tags: angular

I downloaded files from boilerplate template and try to run angular ui. I have package.json as below

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.13.3",
    "@angular/cli": "^7.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.6",
    "@angularclass/hmr": "^2.1.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.3.2",
    "@types/node": "^10.12.15",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.3.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.2.1",
    "karma": "^3.1.4",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.4",
    "karma-jasmine": "^2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "nswag": "^12.0.7",
    "protractor": "^5.4.2",
    "ts-node": "^7.0.1",
    "tslint": "^5.7.0",
    "typescript": "3.1.6",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.0.3"
  }
```

and when I run npm start, I get an error in root.module.ts

```
ERROR in ./src/root.module.ts 39:24
Module parse failed: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level (39:24)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|                     if (shouldLoadLocale()) {
|                         var angularLocale = convertAbpLocaleToAngularLocale(abp.localization.currentLanguage.name);
>                         import(`@angular/common/locales/${angularLocale}.js`)
|                             .then(function (module) {
|                             registerLocaleData(module.default);
```

I don't have webpack.config.js but I have only protractor.config.js and karma.config.js
I guess I miss something.

What do I miss?

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem.

- List item
- removing node_modules
- removing package.lock.json
- upgrading some @angular packages to the latest one
- and then npm i worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `"module": "commonjs"` into `tsconfig.app.json` file. as like below

1. Go to the file `tsconfig.app.json`
2. Add `"module": "commonjs"` line as shown in the picture

[image]

3. Now `serve` project again.